# Set a variable onCreated

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to set `this.editMode` to a variable but it just doesn't seem to return a value. I'm not sure if I'm setting the variable correctly or if it is something else entirely.

```
Template.user.onCreated(function() {

    var classes = function (){

        var class = (this.profile.class && this.profile.class.name);


        if (class != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    };

    this.editMode = new ReactiveVar(classes);
});
```

Comment: A reactive var can't be created from a function.

Comment: that sucks. Is there a simple way to do it then?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? What are you trying to be reactive to?

Comment: It's a form. I want to check to make sure the user has selected a class. If the user has selected a class it will display a list, otherwise it displays the form. I want it reactive so that on event clicks (fa-pencil) it switches between the form and the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template html,

```
<template name="user">
    {{#if isEditMode}}
       <div class="btn btn-info save-user">
          <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
       </div>
       <!-- your edit form here -->
    {{else}}
       <div class="btn btn-info edit-user">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
       </div>
       <!-- your view form here -->
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Then in your template javascript, first add a reactive variable to the template instance, then add click event listeners that edit this reactive variable. Use a helper to retrieve the mode to display the form or list accordingly.

```
Template.user.onCreated(function() {
    this.isEditMode = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.user.events({
    'click .edit-user': function (ev, template) {
        template.isEditMode.set(true);
    },
    'click .save-user': function (ev, template) {
        //validate and save user data here and in the callback, set
        template.isEditMode.set(false);
    }
});

Template.user.helpers({
    'isEditMode': function () {
        var template = Template.instance();
        return template.isEditMode.get();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

If I understand you correctly, you want to show the form or list based on user information when template is loaded. If that is the case, the problem with your code is, it is not calling the function. Change it to something like this,

```
Template.user.onCreated(function() {
   var template = this;
   template.editMode = new ReactiveVar(false); 
   template.autorun(function () {
       var data = Template.currentData(); //Is template data your user?   
       var isClassAvailable = (data.profile.class && data.profile.class.name) ? true : false;
       template.editMode.set(isClassAvailable); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kishor. This doesn't check the state of the form before setting the reactiveVar which is what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to include that?

Comment: @bp123 Can you explain a bit more on what do you mean by state of the form. I didn't get it. :).

Comment: No problem. I want to check that a portion of the is complete. Effectively I want to check if the database contains specific information. If the user has already chosen a class then the list displays onload however if the user hasn't selected a class then it loads the form onload.

Comment: @bp123 Updated the answer, let me know, if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks mate. That's working now. You have //validate and save user data here and in the callback. How do I get autoform to do it's normal validation before it switches views?

Comment: @bp123 You can use `AutoForm.validateForm(formId)` to validate it manually but I have never worked with autoform, so I don't know :). You may have to ask a different question for that.

Comment: Thanks Mate. You've been a big help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use Session for such use case.

```
Session.setDefault('userEditMode', false);

Template.user.rendered = function() {

    var classes = function (){

        var class = (this.profile.class && this.profile.class.name);

        if (class != null) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        };
    };

    Session.set('userEditMode',classes);
});
```

**UPDATE** (for your comment)

You should check with Session variable, instead of classes function.

So in your template use:

```
{{#if isEditMode}} {{> form}} {{else}} {{> list}} {{/if}}
```

And in your template helper:

```
Template.user.helpers({
    isEditMode : return Session.get('isEditMode');
});
```

As an alternative if you use [handlebars-helpers for meteor](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers), you can directly access Session variable in your template:

```
{{#if $.Session.get 'isEditMode'}} {{> form}} {{else}} {{> list}} {{/if}}
```

With this you do not need to define your helper.

Comment: Hi Areca. How do I add this to the template. I've tried `{{#if classes}} {{> form}} {{else}} {{> list}} {{/if}}` but that doesn't work